# Connecting remote powershell using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am coding in vb.net and connecting to remote powershell inorder to execute the command. Simple commands are working fine but complex command which has loops are unable to execute.
 Throws Exception: "Script block literals are not allowed in restricted language mode or a Data section." Please help.. Unable to find any issue.

```
  Public Function RemotePowerShell(username, securepassword, uri, connectionInfo)
    Dim powershell1 As PowerShell
    Dim creds As New PSCredential(username, securepassword)
    Dim runspace As Runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo)
    Try
          runspace.Open()

        'invoke the powershell to obtain the results
        Dim result As Collection(Of PSSession) = powershell1.Invoke(Of PSSession)()


        For Each current As ErrorRecord In powershell1.Streams.[Error]
            Console.WriteLine(("The following Error happen when opening the remote Runspace: " & current.Exception.ToString() & " | InnerException: " & current.Exception.InnerException)

        Next

        If result.Count <> 1 Then
            Throw New Exception("Unexpected number of Remote Runspace connections returned.")
        End If

        ' Set the runspace as a local variable on the runspace
        powershell1 = PowerShell.Create()
        ' associate the runspace with powershell
        powershell1.Runspace = runspace

        Dim Command = New PSCommand()
 ' this line which has $_ causing the problem 
        Command.AddScript("get-mailbox -identity 'SomeName'| Get-MailboxPermission | ?{($_.IsInherited -eq $False) -and -not ($_.User -match ""NT AUTHORITY"")}")
        powershell1.Commands = Command
        powershell1.Runspace = runspace
        Dim results As New Collection(Of PSObject)

        results = powershell1.Invoke()
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        runspace.Dispose()
        runspace = Nothing

        'Finally dispose the powershell and set all variables to null to free up any resources.
        powershell1.Dispose()
        powershell1 = Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Are you doing this for practice or do you wish to achieve something job-wise? If the latter, why can't you use the Invoke-Command?

Comment: Can you please let me know how you use that . I tried might be I am missing with proper syntax

Comment: Try: Invoke-Command -computername localhost -ScriptBlock { Get-Process }

with different scripts around that you can add a loop "for each computer" and so on. Also, remember to pass credentials so that you can actually do what you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i used pipeline and setting the command Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned